# What does it mean if performance of two different iterations of the same network (CNN model) varies a lot?

Tags: machine-learning, convolutional-neural-network, object-recognition

So I trained CNN model for people detection on caltech-pedestrian dataset:
Then I was curious and evaluated the model in every 1000th iteration on Evaluation toolbox(I guarantee, there is no bug in evaluation).

However, plot of the performance does not look so good. The miss rate spikes between 20K(20,000) and 30K iterations.

I am confused what does that mean. I mean usually we would expect the miss rate to decrease as we train the model more.

I am using yolo object detection network https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/master/cfg/tiny-yolo-voc.cfg

So learning options are the same as https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/master/src

[image]

I also tried 10x smaller learning rate.
However, no luck:
[image]

Comment: It's weird to have such similar learning curves given the different learning and miss rates. What's your optimizer? How big is your network? Are you minibatching? If so, what size?

Comment: I am using darknet framework. It uses momentum for update. My network is really big, I put link for configuration (it is modified version of inceptionV3). Batch size is 64. YOLO waits to fill the batch by performing multiple subdivisions. https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/master/src/convolutional_layer.c#L510

Comment: It could just be an artifact of minibatching, which introduces noise that has a desirable regularization effect. See what happens when you increase the minibatch size.

Answer (score 1):

This is a relatively common phenomena called [double descent](https://openai.com/blog/deep-double-descent/).